# #to_json throws "show.json.jbuilder missing"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In #show I have this code:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :show }
    format.json { @my_item.to_json }
  end
end


private

def set_trip
  @my_item = MyModel.find(params[:id])
end
```

When I'm requesting "/my_models/1.json", it throws an exception:

```
Showing app/views/my_models/show.json.jbuilder where line #1 raised:

Missing partial my_models/_my_model with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "app/views"
  * "/home/fdsafds/.gem/ruby/2.4.2/gems/apitome-0.1.0/app/views"
```

Why is that? Do I have to have jbuilder? Why can't it simply convert an object to json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `jbuilder`.

You need to call `render` in your json format block. See the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-json) on rendering json.

> 2.2.8 Rendering JSON
>
> JSON is a JavaScript data format used by many Ajax libraries. Rails
>   has built-in support for converting objects to JSON and rendering that
>   JSON back to the browser: render json: @product
>
> You don't need to call to_json on the object that you want to render.
>   If you use the :json option, render will automatically call to_json
>   for you.

Comment: what's the difference between "my_obj.to_json" and "json: my_obj"?

Comment: Nothing, it's the render call that makes a difference. You're effectively not returning anything to the controller to display without a `render` call, so it defaults to looking for a template to render.

Comment: `format.json { render @my_model }` --> still the same error -- missing partial